# change drawable shape parameter programmatically

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

i a m looking to make a ring loading effect and to do that i have to change the dashWidth value.

I want to do that programmatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="oval">

  <stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#8FFFFFFF" 
    android:dashWidth="304dp"
    android:dashGap="500dp"/>

  <size 
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: then see what kind of Drawable is that, you can get the background Drawable by calling `View#getBackground()`

Comment: yes but how can i change the parameter ? i cant find a setter for the dash width !

Comment: what kind of Drawable was that?

Comment: it's an ovale shape in an xml file

Comment: did you call `View#getBackground()` ?

Comment: yes and it return a Drawable that dont have any setter to change the dashWidth

Comment: yes it returns Drawable, so what kind of Drawable was that?

Comment: a Drawable that i cast to ShapeDrawable

Comment: not GradientDrawable? are you sure?

Comment: Man you are the best it worked when i casted it to GradientDrawable and used the setStroke method. thank you a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As psink sad it's possible to access the dashGap and dashWidth attribute from the stroke.
I just used the setStroke method on the background object after casting it to a GradientDrawable

```
GradientDrawable background = (GradientDrawable)backgroundContainer.getBackground();
background.setStroke(3, Color.WHITE, 50, 500);
```

Comment: Yep, casting to GradientDrawable works! I use it to set background color by calling **setColor()**.